# Am I likely to get a performance improvement upgrading iphone 4 from ios6 to 7.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance

I have an iPhone 4 that I didn't upgrade to iO7 because I'd heard a lot of people saying it hurt the phone's performance, and my phone's performance was already pretty terrible.

I've seen people saying that 7.1 is [specifically faster for an iPhone 4](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/03/ios-7-1-on-the-iphone-4-as-good-as-its-going-to-get/?comments=1), but only in comparison to iOs 7.0

If I upgrade my iphone 4 to 7.1 will it run better or worse? I use it as a backup device, mainly for music, so I'm ok doing without the improvements, but if I'm likely to get a performance improvement than I'm all over it.

Answer (score 1):

7.1 is probably the best performance that you'll see on the iPhone 4. While the loading times for apps seems to be cut by a half a second or more for most, there's only so much you can do for a 4-year-old processor. I'd say the upgrade is well worth it. You won't see all the features that the 4S and 5 iterations see, but its still an increase in performance -- I'd say go for it.

Comment: What are you basing your question on?  It is almost a certainty that upgrading an old device with a newer OS will result in slower performance.  Do you have any evidence of what you are saying?